# Including js file in handlerbar

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, handlebars.js

I am not able to recieve any calls to my js file. What could be the problem? Using MVC

view, file.hbs

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 onClick="test()">Title</h2>
  {{>list}}
</div>

<script src='/public/js/game.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

public game.js file

```
function test(){
   alert("alert");
}
```

router file

```
'use strict';

 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();
 const GameController = require('../controllers/game');

 router.get('/', GameController.initialize);

 module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function cannot be called unless it was defined in the same file or one loaded before the attempt to call it.
Means, you need to move the script-tag before the div-tag and it should work. The console should also give you some hints.

Comment: Do you got any errors in the console? Mostly the errors are caused by wrong source-paths. You can try to put the game.js in the same folder like the file.hbs and change the src path to "game.js"

Comment: Yap, error: "GET /game/game.js 404" Also tried to move them to the same folder.

Comment: Yeah, then it is a problem with the path. If you got the game.js file in a folder game you should access it via src='game/game.js' without the leading slash.

Comment: I managed to fix this, the problem was that I should not be using "public" in path, so src="/js/game.js" solved the problem. Thanks for you help!